Clipping the output of an Op-Amp using Zener diodes
I would like to clip the output of my circuit to =/- 5V using Zener diodes,  I am not sure what the best way of doing this is. I have come up with two circuits that I think in principle achieve the same goal, is there one that's preferable? Is there an even better way of achieving this clipping without introducing too much noise to the circuit?



You should include a resistor between the op-amp output and the diodes, as they will draw much more current during clipping. Also, from my experience, low power diodes (below 2-5W) react slower than the more powerful ones, so you should also try zeners of a higher rated power and see how they work for you. As you have mentioned, noise may become an issue when using zener diodes.

One option might be to use a rail-to-rail opamp and limit the supply voltages to +/- 5 V. Some Schottky diodes can be used to limit the input voltage to within a couple hundred millivolts of the rails although the LM1677 I used in the sim says it has internal diodes for protection, check the data sheet for whatever opamp you try.
Here's an LTspice simulation of what that might look like.

